# Authorize a mvc4 controller based on a particular role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller named "Add", I only want to authorize admin roles, and I stored the roles in `enum Role`,

```
public enum Role { 
     Member = 0,
     Administrator = 100
}
```

Without specifying roles, controller is authorized, but when I tried applying the role like this,

```
[Authorize(Roles = Role.Administrator.ToString())]
public class AddController : Controller
{
}
```

and tried to build the solution, it gives me an error.

```
Error   1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type  C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Direct-Edited\Deor.Direct\src\Direct.Web\Controllers\AddController.cs    11  23  Direct.Web
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameters to an attribute must be constant. The easiest thing is to use a hard coded value.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

Another option is to define your roles in a static class.

```
public static class AppRoles
{
   public const string AdminRole = "Administrator";
}
```

Then in your controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.AdminRole)]
```

Comment: i already tried this, but this always redirect to login page again when this controller called

Comment: That is the default behavior when a user hits that controller and they do not have the required Role. Are you sure the user you are testing with has the correct role?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give value like this, it will take a const or a string value

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AdminRole")] //String value here
public class AddController : Controller
{
}
```

Second alternative is to check the request in a base controller, if it is for add controller, then allow only if role is desired role.

Comment: i already tried this, but this always redirect to login page again when this controller called

Comment: even if the role is admin role??, others will be redirected for sure as they wont be authorized.

Comment: yes .if the role is admin then also, it redirected to login